# Django DRF how to validate captcha response for server side

Tags: python, reactjs, python-3.x, django, recaptcha

I amusing nextjs as my frontend. I am struggling to validate server site captcha response. I want data will be not inserted in my database until captcha verification sucess. I tried [drf-recaptcha](https://pypi.org/project/drf-recaptcha/)  package. Here is my code:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['rest_framework_recaptcha',] #included in my installed app
DRF_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY = '< my_secrect key>'
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_recaptcha import ReCaptchaField

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recaptcha = ReCaptchaField()
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

**my API views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def contact_forms_api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation '''
        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        values = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        result = json.load(response)
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''
        if result['success']:
            data = request.data
            serializer = ContactSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                print(serializer.data)
                return Response({
                    'status': True,
                    'message': 'sucess'
                })

            return Response({
                'status': False,
                'message': serializer.errors

            })
```

here is my nexjs code:

I am using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha) in my frontend application.  here my code sometings look like:

```
<form onSubmit={SubmitContact}>
<input type="text"/>
   <ReCAPTCHA
      sitekey="my_captcha site ke=y"
      onChange={handleRecaptcha}
             
    />
<form>
```

here is my SubmitContact function look like this:

```
  const res = await axios.post(url,data,{headers: headers}
            )
```

inside data variable I am passing user data and passing this `headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }` as header.

**Conclution:**  I know this question is very long but I think I need to explain everything so you can understand my problems.

Right now anyone can submit data using my contact froms but I want they must be verify captcha and the captcha response must be verified from serverside.

Comment: Which part of the code isn't working? Are you not getting a response from Google's endpoint? Is result['succes'] always False? Is the form not submitted?

Comment: @Vincent I am getting response in my client-side but can't verify this response in serverside.

Comment: my code not working when I added  ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation '''

Comment: Which part of that isn't working? Does recaptcha_response contain a value? What does response contain?

Comment: ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation ''' to  ''' End reCAPTCHA validation ''' part not working. yes it contains captcha response. I can see the response from my client side

Comment: I see, but which line in there isn't working? Does the Google endpoint return an error as a result, or Does recaptcha_response not contain a value?

Comment: I said '' Begin reCAPTCHA validation ''' to ''' End reCAPTCHA validation ''' not working.  WHich line exactly I don't know but I can sure it will be  '' Begin reCAPTCHA validation ''' to ''' End reCAPTCHA . Google endpoint don't  return error. I can see captcha response in my client side.

Comment: The captcha response on the client side is the value (g-recaptcha-response) you need to POST from the server side to the Google url. Did you manage to get the value for g-recaptcha-response in your code?

Comment: I post my code. please see. I was using similar code in my another django project which was working but it's not working in Django REST.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I can help you any further. The issue you're having is unclear to me.